# Reading a Qos Log file and making a report out of it

Tags: java

I need to read out multiple  Qos log files and make a report out of it

I need to take a particular date range like 1-1-2015 to 15-1-2015 from user to find logs in that range only

Example:Consider below lines as some of the entries of a Qos Log file

****[CD8C] ComputerName:NITIN UserID:GO ankurjain Station 9900  LanId: | (11/24 19:50:30) | Client is disconnected from agent.

[CD8C] ComputerName:NITIN UserID:GO ankurjain Station 9900  LanId: | (11/24 19:50:35) | Client is connected to agent.

[D44C] ComputerName:APT UserID:A0005 Kelley Zajac Station 1  LanId: | (11/24 18:53:47) | Client is disconnected from agent.

[D44C] ComputerName:APT UserID:A0005 Kelley Zajac Station 1  LanId: | (11/24 18:53:52) | Client is connected to agent.

[D45A] ComputerName:APT UserID:A0005 Kelley Zajac Station 1  LanId: | (11/24 19:31:30) | Client is disconnected from agent.

[D45A] ComputerName:APT UserID:A0005 Kelley Zajac Station 1  LanId: | (11/24 19:31:40) | Client is connected to agent.****

Now i need to analyse and make a report out of it which looks like:

Computer Name,  No. of client Disconnects for that computer name in that date         range in descending order

Comment: and what is the question?

Comment: How do I make this report using hashmap?

Comment: so do you expect us to write a programm for you? Thats not how it works!

Comment: Don't worry brother , I was not asking you to write a program....but i was asking you to guide the way to me